# Getting a facebook profile picture from an email address

Tags: image, facebook, gravatar

I'm trying to get a user's facebook profile picture based on their email address. Effectively, I want to offer my users the option between using Gravatar for their image, or Facebook. However, the only way I know of to get a user's facebook image is via:

`http://graph.facebook.com/[FBOOK USERNAME]/picture?type=large`

Since the usernames may vary between facebook and my site, I would like to do this via email address rather than username. How do I query for someone's facebook profile picture via email address?

Comment: Can you really do that?  It seems a bit of a security issue to enable retrieval of facebook data based on an email address that is likely private user data.  Of course, facebook's definition of private may be looser than others'.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I thought about using the user.name in the url but that only works if a user has set up a facebook username on www.facebook.com/username.

Comment: It seems the Sparrow (http://sparrowapp.com/) email client is doing this however it requires you to authenticate against facebook.

Answer (score 24):

I see this question has a couple of years already but the same search approach can be taken using the Graph API:

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={EMAIL}&type=user`

You can try this on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). You don't get the profile picture directly but you get the user id which you can easily use to get the public profile picture.

`https://graph.facebook.com/{UID}/picture`

Comment: Exactly - excellent answer. :) The thing that a lot of people miss is that, when using the Graph API in this way, you're limited to getting the *public* profile picture. If a user's settings are such that their profile picture is private, you won't be able to get it (which, I think most of us would agree, is how it should be).

Comment: it says "A user access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: not possible to search in this way anymore - must have been abused way too much unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be an official way to do what you are asking. It seems like facebook has made this closed on purpose, probably something to do with privacy. Its actually really easy to do this in a few screen-scraping steps though:

1. Visit http://www.facebook.com/#!/search.php?q=#{USERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS}&type=all&init=srp
2. If page returns "No results found for your query.", then they don't have a profile.
3. Otherwise, the page will contain a thumbnail of the user for that email address. (something like http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs227.ash2/48219_72120057_3223_q.jpg)

I could write a sinatra app to do this in about 5 minutes, if anyone would like me to.

But I think gravatar and facebook should just be friends.

Comment: I really do like this - I wouldn't screen-scrape but I can definitely use the search results to automatically get users' facebook-IDs, and use the method in my question. However, searching only seems to work when you're logged in, which defeats me doing this programatically

Answer (score -2):

What you're asking to do is part of why Facebook Connect exists.

Using their not-too-cleverly-named XFBML you can request the image directly:
`<fb:profile-pic uid="1256100362" facebook-logo="true" size="thumb"> </fb:profile-pic>`

But you have to implement logins with FB Connect first...

Comment: this still uses the UID though - you can already do that without Facebook Connect via, in the case you mentioned, http://graph.facebook.com/1256100362/picture?type=large

Comment: yup, it's a shame that we can't do that with an md5(email) just like gravatar does