# Get facebook profile ID or Picture by Email

Tags: facebook, email, profile, image

I would like to get the profile ID or picture using the users email , something like this
http://fb-tut.4p-tech.co.il/index.html

I could parse this page
http://www.facebook.com/search.php?init=dir&q=&type=users
But i was wondering if there is a cleaner simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={EMAIL}&type=user&access_token={ACCESSTOKEN}

This gives the ID

Comment: How do you get the ACCESSTOKEN?

Comment: Accesstoken is part of the authentication flow with Facebook's api (OAuth)

Comment: Currently, Facebook doesn't allow this now as I have tried and received an error which is the following: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/453298034751100?browse=search_516534c213df06064266897 I am currently thinking of following nathan's answer from [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129910/getting-a-facebook-profile-picture-from-an-email-address) page

Comment: I haven't worked with FB api in a while ... and they made substantial changes since i wrote the answer so it's possible that this might not work now.

But it should be something similar, i guess the principle is still the same