# Getting Facebook Profile Pic using email address in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, facebook, image, email, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Profile Pic from email address and display on my site and i dont have user ids, i can get it (to some extent) when i access via web and [this post was great help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129910/getting-a-facebook-profile-picture-from-an-email-address). but i am unable to get pic via C# application as solution on linked post returns middle page which contain js code with some meta tags to forward it to next result page. Tried FQL but it needs user id (indexable column).

when i try https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={EMAIL}&type=user it returns authentication error but http://www.facebook.com/#!/search.php?q=#{USERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS}&type=all&init=srp works better but this second one returns middle page with js code.

Note: i don't have user ids and i am not using any facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are no longer able to query via email address.  When Facebook updated their Graph API they removed the ability to search for the user's ID.  The user's ID is the information you need to pull their profile photo.

see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

Thus, this is not possible.